# How create task with celery in django? POO issue?

Tags: python, django, oop, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to set up a task with Django and Celery. The Celery and Django configuration is okay, nothing to report on that side. However, I have a problem, I think with the writing, of my code in OOP. I can't locate where the problem is. It's an argument problem, 4 arguments are expected by delay(), but my method only expects 3. Here are the files and what I tried to do, as well as the error trace.

#### My files

helpers.py

I want to create a task for `run_test_optimization method`

```
class MachineLearniaXHelpers(MagicModels):
    def __init__(self, data_dict, target_name, type_model, test_size = 0.33, random_state = 42, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.test_size = test_size
        self.random_state = random_state
        self.process = DataProcessor(
            data=data_dict,
            target_name=target_name
        )
        self.metrics = MetricsScorer(type_model=type_model)
        self.model = self.several_algorythme(type_model, **kwargs)
    
    @staticmethod
    def split_data(data_dict):
        return train_test_split(*data_dict)
        
    @staticmethod   
    def train_model(model, X, y):
        model.fit(X, y)
    
    def run_test_optimization(self):
        dict_result = []
        for model in self.model:
            feature_model, values = self.process.transform_dict_to_array_structure()
            x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = self.split_data(values)
            self.train_model(model, x_train, y_train)
            dict_metrics_train = self.metrics.choice_metrics_by_type_model(y_train, model.predict(x_train))
            dict_metrics_test = self.metrics.choice_metrics_by_type_model(y_test, model.predict(x_test))
            dict_result.append({
                "name_model" : model.__class__.__name__,
                "features_model" : feature_model,
                "train_performances" : dict_metrics_train,
                "test_performances" : dict_metrics_test
            })
        return dict_result
```

tasks.py

create my task `task_run_test_optimization`

```
from celery import shared_task
from .helpers import MachineLearniaXHelpers

@shared_task
def task_run_test_optimization(data_dict, target_name, type_model):
    constructor = MachineLearniaXHelpers(
        data_dict,
        target_name,
        type_model
        )
    dict_result = constructor.run_test_optimization()
    return dict_result
```

views.py

API post method, the task method is here `task_run_test_optimization`

```
class MachineLearningXView(APIView):
    serializer_class = BuildModelMLSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, UserPermissionMachineLearniaX]


    def post(self, request):
        if not self.request.session.exists(self.request.session.session_key):
            self.request.session.create()
        
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            data = request.data.get('data')
            target = serializer.data.get('target_name')
            type_model = serializer.data.get('test_type')
            result = task_run_test_optimization.delay(data, target, type_model) # probleme is here
            print(result)
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

result send me an id in my console, the post request is ok:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
February 08, 2023 - 17:25:28
Django version 4.1.5, using settings 'ialab.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
829e66ee-925f-4aff-8c42-49420e5758ce <-- PRINT result IS HERE
[08/Feb/2023 17:25:47] "POST /api/machinelearniax HTTP/1.1" 200 0
```

But in my celery worker, i'have this error:

```
[2023-02-08 17:25:47,813: INFO/MainProcess] Task api.tasks.task_run_test_optimization[829e66ee-925f-4aff-8c42-49420e5758ce] received
[2023-02-08 17:25:47,897: ERROR/MainProcess] Task api.tasks.task_run_test_optimization[829e66ee-925f-4aff-8c42-49420e5758ce] raised unexpected: TypeError('task_run_test_optimization() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\basti\Desktop\IALab\ialab\.ialabenv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 451, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\basti\Desktop\IALab\ialab\.ialabenv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\trace.py", line 734, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: task_run_test_optimization() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

the task is received but not working.

#### where is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Possible case and solution #1.

You might have had `task_run_test_optimization` accepting 4 arguments initially. You've run Celery and it loaded this task and its signature into the memory.

Then you might have changed `task_run_test_optimization` signature to take 3 arguments, but you forgot to **reload Celery**. As a result, you are trying to call the task with 3 arguments, but Celery still keeps the old version of the task (task with 4 arguments).

### Possible case and solution #2:

Maybe you have 2 different tasks named the same: "task_run_test_optimization" and your views.py imports the wrong one? Make sure you import the right one.

Comment: Thank you for your response, case 1 solved the problem. I accept the answer.